# What's the difference between micro-particle and micron-particle?

Tags: differences, nouns, synonyms

A simple Google search gave me:

```
Micro-particle 564,000
Micron-particle 309,000
```

Are they interchangeable or is there a difference between the two?
Here is an example:

> Air filters remove dust, pollen and other micro(micron) particles from the air.

Comment: @downvoter: An explanation of why would be polite for newcomers.

Comment: Yes, punishing without explaining the reason is absolutely useless and only characterises the punisher him/herself. Not from better side, too. So, my +1 to compensate the injustice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Micron* is another term for a micrometre. If you look at your Google results for `"micron-particle"` again, you'll see that the majority of the results are either referring to particles of a specified size measured in microns (e.g., a 0.5 micron particle or a 3 micron particle), or actually have the text *sub-micron particle*, not just *micron particle*. A *sub-micron particle* is a particle that is smaller than a micron in size.

A *micro-particle* is a particle of a size in the micro- scale. The exact range included in this is not well defined as far as I'm aware, but the Wikipedia article on [microparticles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microparticles) claims that is between 0.1 and 100 μm in size, which is probably reasonable. In specific fields within science and engineering the use of the term may be more tightly defined.

If the term *micron-particle* is used (without being preceded by a measurement) then it might be interpreted equivalently to *micro-particle*, or it might be interpreted as similar but with a tighter range. However, as a reader I would consider it incorrect and therefore slightly jarring.

In your example, *micro particle* is the correct term to use, since you are not giving a specific value for the size of particle.

I should also note that outside of science and engineering, the *micro-* prefix might be used or interpreted with less precision, in which case a *micro particle* would just refer to *a very small particle*.

Comment: I agree with your assessment and will use microparticle, thank you.